# jquery array of checkboxes contains the last one checked

Tags: php, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes that I'm trying to pass through POST via AJAX/PHP.  When I fill the array it's only picking up the last one.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="committee[]" value="membership">Membership <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="committee[]" value="operations">Operations <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="committee[]" value="membership">Board <br/>
```

Javascript

```
$("#save").click(function (e) { 
 ...
 var committee = { 'committee[]' : []};
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
   committee['committee[]'].push($(this).val());
 });

 $.ajax({
  url: 'save.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
  ...
  committee: committee
  }
 });
});
```

On the `save.php` all I'm doing at this point is `print_r($_POST);` and seeing that only the last checked box shows up.  I know it's something I'm doing wrong in the `input:checked` function, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Can you really set the name as something[] and process it like an array? I never knew that

Comment: You can process commitee[] as an array in server side. But in client side it will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That array index with "[]" probably causes problems. Do this instead:

```
  var committee = new Array();
      $('input:checked').each(function(){
       committee.push($(this).val());
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checked").map(function (i,e) { return $(this).val();})
```

will return the array with the values of the checked checkboxes.
So:

```
var committee = $("input:checked").map(function (i,e) { return $(this).val();});
$.ajax({
  url: 'save.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
  ...
  committee: committee
  }
 });
```

Comment: Btw: are TWO of your values named "membership", which may lead to confusion, or it's an error?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a 
$('#save').click(function(){
$('#hiddendiv').post('save.php');});

or onclick=$('#hiddendiv').post('save.php');

And have the save.php treat the files like this $test=$_POST['committee'];